# Using SQL to create a query of what grid location generates the most income in a shop

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am new to SQL and databases and I have created a basic db for a shop. Tables are: Purchase, Item, Product. I am trying to create a query that will pull back which grid had the most income. I have tried the code below:

```
SELECT PRODUCT.LATITUDE
       , PRODUCT.LONGITUDE
       , SUM(PRICE)"TOTAL"
       , PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID
       , PURCHASE.PURCHASE_ID
       , ITEM.PURCHASE_ID,
FROM PRODUCT
     , PURCHASE
     , ITEM, 
WHERE PURCHASE.PURCHASE_ID = ITEM.PURCHASE_ID 
AND ITEM.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID;
```

Any tips on how best to bring back these details?

Thanks!

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: You also need `GROUP BY` here.

Comment: Another tip: proper layout prevents confusion. The code posted here has trailing commas. I don't know whether that's just an artefact of your question, but if they are in your actual code the query won't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT  PRODUCT.LATITUDE
   , PRODUCT.LONGITUDE
   , SUM(PRODUCT.PRICE)  "TOTAL"
FROM PUCHARSE JOIN ITEM ON PUCHARSE.ID = ITEM.PUCHARSE_ID JOIN PRODUCT ON PRODUCT.ID = ITEM.PRODUCT_ID   
GROUP BY 
PRODUCT.LATITUDE,
PRODUCT.LONGITUDE
ORDER BY SUM(PRODUCT.PRICE) DESC
NULLS LAST;
```

Assuming that PRODUCT table contains information about geolocation in shop, price and from table Purchase you need only PRODUCT_ID(each sold out products is single row in this table - by this you have amount of sold out products in history).

Comment: Okay thanks, however I don't have PRODUCT_ID stored in the PURCHASE table due to a purchase possibly having more than one product. What is the syntax to join 3 columns ie. Purchase > Item > Product


PURCHASE
PURCHASE_ID
PURCHASE_TIME
PURCHASE_DATE
  
ITEM
ITEM_ID
PURCHASE_ID
PRODUCT_ID

PRODUCT
PRODUCT_ID
LATITUDE
LONGITUDE
PRICE
PRICE_RANGE
PRODUCT_NAME

Comment: I have changed code in main answer, please check it now.